# List folders greater than 10G and mail to respective owners about the usage

Tags: find, directory, disk-usage

In our environment, we have an NFS mount which contains all users home directories.

I want to find the users whose home directories sizes are greater than 10G and send a notification to them. I tried:

```
du -sh * | sort -hr
```

This worked like a charm, but I could not find the command to extract the directories of size > 10 G.

I tried `find . -size +10G -exec ls -lhS {} \;` but it didn't work.

What's the best way to find/extract the directories with size greater than 10G?

Comment: Have you considered just using the automatic emails built into the quota system? http://linux.die.net/man/8/warnquota

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it.

Where the first column (size) exceeds 10gb, output the second column (directory name)

```
du -sk * | awk '$1 > 10485760 { print $2 }'
```

Or as requested, to show in human readable form, as below.  The regular expression ensures column 1 ends in a G (gigabytes) and the substr part strips the final letter from column 1 and looks to see if it's more than 10.

```
du -sh * | awk '$1 ~ /G$/ && substr($1,0,length($1)-1) > 10 { print $0 }'
```

Example:

```
du -sh *
2.5G    steve
du -sh * | awk '$1 ~ /G$/ && substr($1,0,length($1)-1) > 1 { print $0 }'
2.5G    steve
du -sh * | awk '$1 ~ /G$/ && substr($1,0,length($1)-1) > 3 { print $0 }'
(no output)
```

Comment: Thanks Steve. This is very helpful. 

But by any chance, can we change list it in human readable format? Preferably like, 

21G mark
17G kannan
15G harry